# Am I doing something wrong the way I'm entering/leaving my car?

Tags: seat, seat-cars, seat-leon

I have finaly got my factory new SEAT Leon and it is great.

But as it is that new, I try to handle it like a raw egg.
So especially one thing confuses me, as for me it hurts (speaking here literarly) and for the car on the long turn I assume I'll break the specific part of my seat.

[image: seat somewhat similiar to what I'm describing]

Here is an photo I made of my seat:
[image: slight difference to the other seat, probably even making the difference]
Its the plastic part, used to upper or lower the drivers seat. It seems to be concaved or at least has a sharp edge facing to the seat.

So the problem is when I'm trying to get out of my seat, to leave the car my leg is getting in contact with the plastic part (pushing down the cloth far enough, as it is as said soft enough) before I'm able to make contact with my left foot to the ground.

Here you can see, that I'm easily able to push down the seat onto the plastic just with my hand. And thats what actually happening every time I leave the car.[image]

So to get my foot on the ground I have to lift my own weight over the plasticpart while thats beeing the only hinge point between my weight and the plastic part.

I allready tried diferent ways of geting out of the car, without any of them beeing able to avoid this situation. I asked friends to try it out, while they all were leaving in the same body moves, all of them said they don't share my complains.

For now I have found that I can avoid it by trying to get out the same way as getting into the car. problem here is, as for getting in my right leg is just stabilizing me as "squeezing" my inward motion. But as for getting out I'm pushing out and have to hold ballance until my left foot touches the ground. This looks pretty stupid and would let me, as soon I will loose a single time my ballance, let me drop backwards onto the street. So no long time solution either.

So on the one hand this puts a hurting pressure on the same part of my leg, everytime I leave the car, letting me after 2 days of owning the car detect allready bruises on my leg, and on the other hand even making me feel more uncomfortable with it the fact, that the part seems to be concaved and therefor soon will break at some point.

So my question is:
Is this problem known?
If so, what is a reasonable workaround, preventing me to pressure my leg against the part.
If not so, what could I be doing wrong and what to change to do it right?

Comment: Are your legs shorter than your friends? have you tried a seat cushion under you?

Comment: @Mauro: Nope, Staying next to them I had in any case so far longer legs than my friends. But my legs still aren't unusual long. A seat cushion might solve this problem. but as my head gets allready decent close to the cars roof, it might result in my head touching the roof. Based on this I'm assuming it might just really be the way I'm moving to get out. I'll later replace the picture with a photo of my excact seat.

Comment: Try moving the seat all the way back when you get out

Comment: @Ben: Just tryed it some minutes ago. This just changes the part of my leg getting pressured. So while this reduces the pain to my leg by splitting it on diferent parts, it doesn't solve my bigger worry of breaking the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's your brand new car, and thus you are extra gentle with her, but trust me, she is much tougher than you think. The plastics are built to bend and buckle, but not to break. It may seem that the plastic is going to break, but in normal circumstances, like the one you mentioned, it will never break.
However, for your peace of mind, you can try taking the door as a support to put most of your body weight when entering/exiting your car. How will you use the door as a support? You can put your hand on the top of the door window frame and put most of your body weight on the door, while you lift yourself up and get inside the car. Same way you can also exit the vehicle. If your window sill has any space or ridge wide enough to get a grip on, you can also take the support of the window sill to exit the car.

### A word of caution

Dont put your weight on the handrest of the door pad. Make sure that the weight is getting loaded on the metal part of the door and not the door pads.

All the best! Happy Motoring!

Comment: On a new vehicle it'll take a while for it to break, but they do break. This happens all the time on early to mid 2000's GM cars and trucks.

Comment: Are you sure the door is designed to support that force for continiously doing it? What about the steering wheel?I figgured out that it wors for me to lift my self by pulling myself to the wheel and stepping over the plastic part works. While doing it on the door worked for me aswell after I tryed as you had told, but I don't feel well by doing so in sense of doing damage to mechanical parts of the door. Couldn't this happen? Or is the wheel more vulnearable to this as the door, anyway?

Comment: @zaibis : You can be rest assured that both the door as well as the steering wheel can easily take the stress that you are talking about. However, if you have to choose between the steering wheel and the door, I would always prefer the door. The door is extremely durable and in most cases will outlast the age of the car.

Comment: so this little metal part of like 70mm x 90mm x 15mm, which is holding the door is that much stress resistant?

Comment: You are'nt going to put 100% of your weight on the door. If you put 100% of your weight on the door by just hanging yourself on your hand, your hand will give up way sooner than door. The weight the door will support only a fraction of your total weight. Also, if you count the no. of times you will get in/out of your car per day, it wont be much, so the stress is not a continuous thing that the door will have to support. Your car SEAT Leon is a great rally car, thus you can be assured that the it's chassis and the components are durable enough for your daily chores.

Answer (score 0):

I'm selfanswering here just to add the way came to handle this. It absolutly is based on Applemans answer and I had put it as comment, but comments aren't welcomed for answers, so:

I'm actually graping with my right hand the steering wheel to pull my self a bit closer to the door, after that graping the doors case with my left hand to pull me out while still using the right hand to stabelize my posture. This avoids anycontact to the plastic part and neither the wheel nor the door is broken yet :P